# Error when connecting ASP.NET MVC Docker database

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, docker

When trying to connect a project with an ASP.NET MVC and Docker database, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I'm using .NET 8.0, SQL Server name is `DESKTOP-HT0STNP`.

The Docker container is present, although it was not launched from the console; the DockerHub repository and the container in Docker Desktop were launched.

The application is deployed on Windows OS I am using SQL Server 2019.

What kind of error could this be?

I tried changing the server name, changing the connection string, nothing helps

*edited, I changed the connection string to
"Server=DESKTOP-HT0STNP,1433;Database=EducationSystem;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;encrypt=false" I have Windows authentication, now I get another error. I changed the code in program.ks a little to this

I added EnableRetryOnFailure to program.cs

throws the error "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RetryLimitExceededException: "The maximum number of retries (5) was exceeded while executing database operations with 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See the inner exception for the most recent failure.""

Moreover, if I remove Database.EnsureCreated() in DbContext, the site turns on, but all those pages that use the database are not included

when I add port 1433 to the windows firewall I get the error "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "An error occurred while logging in for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN.'"

I don’t know what else to do, I checked the connection in SSMS and connections are allowed there, the firewall is enabled if anything

Perhaps the problem is that I have not configured the container to use separate user credentials or other suitable authentication mechanisms in docker

My dockerfile looks like that `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SQLServerCourse/SQLServerCourse.csproj", "SQLServerCourse/"]
COPY ["SQLServerCourse.DAL/SQLServerCourse.DAL.csproj", "SQLServerCourse.DAL/"]
COPY ["SQLServerCourse.Domain/SQLServerCourse.Domain.csproj", "SQLServerCourse.Domain/"]
COPY ["SQLServerCourse.Service/SQLServerCourse.Service.csproj", "SQLServerCourse.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./SQLServerCourse/./SQLServerCourse.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SQLServerCourse"
RUN dotnet build "./SQLServerCourse.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./SQLServerCourse.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SQLServerCourse.dll"]`

if this is the case, what should I do?

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=True` means you are using Windows authentication.  What do you specify User and Password for?

Comment: DESKTOP-HT0STNP won't be found if it's inside docker. And if it's name of your computer, then it won't be found because server is probably not running on 1433 port exposed from docker. Try to follow some docker sql server tutorials perhaps

Comment: Can you connect to the instance using SSMS or other tools? SQL Server for Linux, and so any SQL Server instances based on [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server), supports connections from neither the Named Pipes nor Shared Memory client protocols. Have you tried forcing use of the TCP/IP client protocol by changing your connection string? e.g.: `Server=DESKTOP-HT0STNP,1433;` or `Server=tcp:DESKTOP-HT0STNP,1433;`, or if all else fails, `Server=tcp:127.0.0.1,1433;`

Comment: What's the output of `docker container ls`? Although the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` images expose port 1433 for connections that's not going to be available on the Docker host unless you also published it with something like `-p 1433:1433` on the `docker run` command line.

Comment: docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                    CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                              NAMES
2a5933262383   sqlservercourse:dev   "C:\\remote_debugger\\…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:63783->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:63782->8081/tcp   SQLServerCourse

Comment: i edited question check it up pls :0